Как решить? TypeError: Passing `parse_mode`, `disable_web_page_preview` or `protect_content` to Bot initializer is not supported anymore
Пишу телеграмм бота на aiogram. Появляется ошибка -  TypeError: Passing `parse_mode`, `disable_web_page_preview` or `protect_content` to Bot initializer is not supported anymore. These arguments have been removed in 3.7.0 version. Use `default=DefaultBotProperties(parse_mode=<ParseMode.HTML: 'HTML'>)` argument instead. Как решить? Вот часть кода где возникает ошибка -
async def main() -> None:
    bot = Bot(botkey, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    dp = Dispatcher(bot)
    dp.include_router(router)
    await bot.delete_webhook()
    await dp.start_polling()

вот импорты -
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, Router, types, F
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, CallbackQuery
from aiogram.enums.parse_mode import ParseMode
from config import botkey
from cryptomus2 import create_invoice, get_invoice
from dbase import create_tables, insert_login, get_login


Попробуй так
from aiogram.client.bot import DefaultBotProperties
from aiogram.enums import ParseMode

bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN, default=DefaultBotProperties(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML))


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Попробуйте использовать более старую версию библиотеки.
Например:
pip install aiogram==3.2.0

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как написать хороший ответ => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer //пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
